# Pass Linux enviromental varibles into a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image that needs some credentials passed from the host-environment. How do I pass Linux environmental variables into dockerfile. No flags attachment only dockerfile.

When I build the Docker Image it fetches packages from a local repo that needs authentication. This is all automated and the credentials depend on the host machine that is running.

I have tried to google it and only found how to pass hard-coded varibles. But I need e.g.

```
export VAR=[PASSWORD]
```

to be passed into the dockerfile.

```
ENV PASSWORD = $VAR
```

Comment: If you need the variables at build time, you should look at the `ARG` statement rather than the `ENV` statement.

Comment: Remember that anything in a Dockerfile can be trivially extracted later by anyone who gets the image.  Even using `ARG` as @HansKilian suggests will compromise whatever credentials you pass in.  [What is the best way to pass AWS credentials to a Docker container?](/questions/36354423/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-aws-credentials-to-a-docker-container) discusses passing one particular type of secret at runtime; [Clone private git repo with dockerfile](/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile) is a more specific case of actually needing a secret during a build.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ARG` with the `ENV` in your `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG name
ENV env_name $name
```

When you build your image, pass the arg from your local environment

```
docker build -t my_image --build-arg name=$MY_LOCAL_ENV_VAR .
```

Comment: (`docker inspect my_image` will show the nominally-secret value in plain text.)